# jQuery draggable - how to access the coordinates

Tags: jquery, coordinates, draggable

How can you get access to the dynamically-changing coordinates of a draggable object? I don't just want the coordinates at `stop`, but a constant stream of position information.

In other words, if I drag `object A` around, I should be able to get `object B` to move around in parallel by (1) observing the changes in `object A` and then (2) applying them to the position of `object B`.

In this code, I want the red block (`obj2`) to move with the blue (`obj1`).

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#obj1 {
   position:fixed;
   top:50px;
   left:50px;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   background-color: blue;
}
#obj2 {
   position:fixed;
   top:150px;
   left:150px;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   background-color: red;
}
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#obj1').draggable();
    })
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="obj1"></div>
    <div id="obj2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `drag` event of draggable:

```
$("#obj1").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        var pos = ui.position;
        $("#obj2").css({
            left: pos.left + 100,
            top: pos.top + 100
        });
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kPEfL/

Answer (score 1):

The draggable plugin has 3 events: start, drag and stop (all of which provide coordinates).
You can bind to the drag event and get in your callback the information you need.

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#events) you can find an example and demo.

Answer (score 1):

the `offsetY` and `offsetY` event properties are suitable for that purpose, you can attach a `drag` handler to fetch them:

```js
$('#obj1').bind('drag', function(event) {
    console.log(event.offsetY); // dymamic y position
    console.log(event.offsetX); // dymamic x position
});
```

Reference:

- [the Draggable demos page](http://threedubmedia.com/demo/drag/)